# Reading Firebase data prevents async method from resolving

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to write an Alexa skill which reads from Firebase

I'm in a position where I have a NodeJS method that gets called when I use the Alexa test console, but if I add in code to retrieve data from Firebase the method hangs until the lambda times out

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'plantsIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const snapshot = (await db.collection('plants').get()).data();
        const names = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().name);

        const speakOutput = 'Get yourself some cool plants like' + names.join(' and ');
        console.log(speakOutput);

        var response = handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();

        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }
};
```

When I run this code I get both the `speakOutput` string and `response` object output into the logs, so I know the code is managing to get that far

I'm suspicious it's something to do with Firebase as if I remove the `db.collection('plants').get()` snippet (and the associated variables) then the code runs to completion

I'm suspicious that it's to do with the method not returning rather than an exception happening, because the output for `response` is the same in the working version (without Firebase `.get()`), and the non-working version

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you amend your 'await' statement slightly does it work? e.g `const snapshot = await db.collection('plants').get();
const data = snapshot.data()

Are you saying your console.log is showing all the correct names? Are the console.logs in the right order? ie. it's not showing the speakOutput after the response log in which case it's down to the async nature. Sorry just trying to clarify! Do your logs show the lambda execution time?

Comment: No apologies needed! I appreciate your response :-). Amending my 'await' statement doesn't make any difference unfortunately. The `console.log` is showing all the correct names, and the logs are coming through in the right order. The CloudWatch logs show that the `console.log`s happen at the time I would expect them too, but then hangs until the Lambda times out (at 10 seconds)